# Why does hinduism not fit in history and archaeology?

Tags: scripture, history, time

Why does hinduism not fit in history and archaeology?
According to the Puranas and the Vedas, Vedas were written 1960000000 years ago (before humans).

Mathabhata happened around 3138 BCE, how can there be death of 1 billion, 660 million and 20,000 men.

Historically, 1804 CE was the year when humans reached a population of 1 billion. Can you explain it?

Comment: Hinduism is actually fits into history and archaeology, but problem is that in history good evidence can lost, and there isn't much of archeological survey in historical place about Mahabharata due to some reasons. There exists Ram Setu, and much of all places has same names of villages from time of Mahabharata and Ramayana, so there is need to done deep research and to find evidence which is likely to lost.

Comment: Vedas and Hinduism (Sanatan Dharma) are eternal. Sanatan means eternal. Mahabharata and Ramayana both are called Itihaasa (history) in hinduism. Only modern western scholars ,   historians  ,  and archeologist  disagree with all this.

Comment: BTW the body section of your post is pretty much unclear. Editing and rephrasing the post will increase the probability of an answer.

Comment: No you cannot explain it. This ia major contradiction.

Comment: I hope you know the science behind the data that you quote. Populations in the past cannot be known precisely. So, suitable approximations are made taking in account the prevalent level of technology, food habits, medicine, etc. Now, leave Hinduism and India, the western scholars don't even know much about these attributes in the western world, where many a ancient civilizations were overrun by barbarian 'monotheistic' cults. (1/2)

Comment: When Indians contend these conclusions by presenting facts such as advanced ayurvedic medicine, advanced body sciences such as hatha yoga, well developed polity defined in arthashastra, they are branded by names such as 'Hindutva goons', 'superstitious', etc. I hope that this dispels some doubts. I know you (questioner), don't like to face these facts, and are only interested in quotes for your agenda, but someone who reads the comments section might benefit.(2/2)

Comment: @lamThat OK but how can more the 1 billion people die in a war that took place are 3000 BCE. Even if you combine the total death in world war 1 and 2 even it will be less 200 million. And what was the population of India at that time.

Comment: Might be more. Why do you assume that the present human civilization is more technically capable than the previous ones. This, in the case of western intellectuals, comes from Hegel's philosophy of history, which propounds 'infinite linear progress'. You know, in mathematics, if you are standing on a circle, but you can't see the entire circle, you think it is a straight line (tangent). So, if this points towards immaturity. Our view recognizes that all life occurs in circles. There are ups and downs. The present, according to us, is a technologically and consequently, morally degenerate time.

Comment: The past was more glorious, as will be the future. What else do you expect from these times, when in the name of psychology, all the westerners could come up with, was the highly perverse idea of infantile sexuality? Raja Yoga, and Buddhist thought by comparison, is much more detailed, much more rational, yet it is rejected, because it does not come with white skin and christianity.

Comment: @lamThat you can write an answer, you can explain Mahabharata but how will you explain 19600000000 year old vedas.

Comment: Look, I don't know where you found the number. I don't claim to know when Mahabharata occured, I am just saying it did, possibly in 3500 BC. Some literature is available that tries to run computer simulations on the solar/constellation positions mentioned in the Mahabharata and Ramayana literature. Remarkably, they happen to be largely consistent, which leads to the date ~3500 for the Mahabharata.

Comment: @lamThat https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranic_chronology#:~:text=Two%20central%20dates%20are%20the,chronology%20started%20at%203102%20BCE.

Comment: I don't claim that Vedas are that old. I don't know how old they are. But, most probably, they are atleast older than the Indus Valley Civilization, which uses town planning and architecture directly mentioned in the vedas. Latest research shows that the origins of IVC might be about 7000 BCE. The inflated numbers come from the original texts because the science of ancient astronomy is lost with the destruction of Hindu knowledge systems. People try to say that they are still intact, which leads to wild guessing/interpretation of puranic texts, but that is simply not the case.

Comment: @lamThat some hindu claim that

Comment: Yes, please read my edited comment, which is just above your comment for the explanation.

At any rate, unlike Abrahamic religions (like Christianity), we are not obsessed with history and dates, to prove that there was some prophet and some particular event occurred on some day, on the basis of which the entire religion rests. Ours is an empirical religion. You see the results of yoga, meditation, etc., you adopt it. No belief system, no heresy hunting, you are left on your own, with maximum personal freedom.

Comment: @lamThat OK but can you answer it

Comment: I want to, but I can't. The answer will be flagged with a citations notice. I don't know whether all I said can be sourced from traditional sources, or famous personalities for quotes/citations. Anyway, if the answer satisfies you, it can be present in the comments section, where it can be read by others too, it it is not deleted by the moderators.

Comment: @lamThat OK but what is the conclusion

Comment: That your claim is wrong. Vedas are not older than 10^n years (I don't want to count n). They can be atleast 10,000 years old, possibly 15k years old. Not older. Plus, the population argument for Mahabharata doesn't hold true because it rests on the assumption that the period was technically backward, which may not be the case. So, Hinduism is compatible with history and archaeology, just that adequate efforts haven't been put in to excavate the right remains. (1/3)

Comment: This is due to the prevailing political atmosphere in the country, where considerable power was held by Marxists, who distorted history for their geopolitical/socio-political agendas. When, you read the currently taught history, you will find that the vedas are dated solely on the basis of some broken pots they have found having no correlation with the vedas, while the dwarka excavation project or the ram setu research project was abandoned. (2/3)

Comment: The current government has launched a project along these lines(read about sindhu sadhana- reasearch vessel), to research about the physical ram setu. Let us see what comes out. If archeology is pursued in the right way, of course it will match with the history of Hinduism. (3/3)

Comment: @lamThat okk thanks